# How do I use InterfaceBuilder files in Xcode subprojects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm developing an iPhone app that is a "module" of another launcher (it doesn't launch from the iPhone home screen). To add this module to the launcher, I have to drop in the xcode file into the parent xcode project (creating a subproject). The subproject uses a NIB file as its view controller and the subproject loads the file using initWithNib:

```
root_view_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[LMU_IP_RootView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMU_IP_RootView" bundle:nil]];
```

When I try to run the parent project, it crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle [...] (loaded)' with name 'LMU_IP_RootView''
```

I'm guessing its because it can't find the NIB file because the root bundle is now the parent project instead of the subproject. I could include the NIB in the parent project and that fixes the error, but doesn't solve my problem.

So my question: How do I use InterfaceBuilder files in a subproject? Do I have to specify a bundle? How do I specify a bundle that refers to this subproject?

Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone be of help? Do I need to clarify or post example files?

Answer (score 0):

When bundle is `nil`, the search is performed in the *main* bundle, not in your subproject bundle. I'm not entirely clear on your app architecture, but try specifying the bundle containing the class as the bundle to search:

```
NSBundle *classBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[LMU_IP_RootView class]];
id vc = [[LMU_IP_RootView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:classBundle]
root_view_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                        initWithRootViewController:vc];
[vc release];
```

Note that a `nil` nib name defaults to "*ClassName*.nib", so `LMU_IP_RootView.nib` will be searched for in this case.

It's generally better to override `-init` in your view controller class so it performs the correct lookup. Then client code doesn't have to worry about what nibs the class needs.

Comment: Ha, well this question is a bit old, but I appreciate your response. Turns out I was just being dense: my "subproject" was actually a static library so when it said it couldn't find the resources...it was because they weren't there. Once I realized my error, I simply included the interface builder files with the app that was referencing the static library and all was well again.